# Dynamic output blob path using Azure function

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function which is triggered by an Event Hub.  Here's a snippet of my index.js file.

```
module.exports = async function (context, eventHubMessages) {
    context.log(`JavaScript eventhub trigger function called for message array ${eventHubMessages}`);

    context.log('Event Hub Trigger: ', JSON.stringify(eventHubMessages));

    const product = context.bindingData.propertiesArray[0].productFilter;

    eventHubMessages.forEach(message =>
    {
      deviceId = message.deviceId;
      context.log('For each message:', JSON.stringify(eventHubMessages));
      context.log('Device ID is', deviceId);
    });
    context.log('Output Device ID is', deviceId);

    if ( product == 'prod1') {


        context.bindings.outputprod1 = eventHubMessages;

    } else if ( product == 'prod2') {

        context.bindings.prod2 = eventHubMessages;
    else {
        context.log("Product not found - " + product);
    }
    return context.done();

};
```

There is a property deviceId in the incoming message.  I want to set the output blob path based on this value.

Here's my function.json file.

```
{
  "bindings": [

    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputprod1",
      "path": "eventtoblobcontainer/prod1/{datetime:yyyy}/{datetime:MM}/{datetime:dd}/prod1_{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "phiotrawdatadev_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlobprod2",
      "path": "eventtoblobcontainer/prod2/{datetime:yyyy}/{datetime:MM}/{datetime:dd}/prod2_{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "phiotrawdatadev_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I add {deviceId} in the path the function gives me error saying No value for named parameter 'deviceId'.  I tried using function return value in the output binding but it gave me the same error.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of using deviceId, could you try using the “name” property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output---configuration

Comment: @silent My whole issue is the output folder path.  I somehow need to send values from my function so that they can be used in the path field in function.json file.

Comment: Did you consider using an SDK instead of a binding?