# Azure function (python) write output to dynamic naming of the output blob path

Tags: python, azure, datetime, azure-functions, azure-storage

I am using an Azure function as Webhook Consumer to receive http events as JSON and storing it on Azure Storage.
I want to do Dynamic naming of the output blob path based on date as shown below. I tried lots of options, but not able to get the desired output.
I am followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888996/dynamic-output-blob-path-using-azure-function) but no luck.

**Excepted write path:**

```
source/
      ctry/
          yyyy/
              mm/ 
                date/
                    hrs/
                        event_{systemtime}.json
```

**function.json:**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputblob",
      "path": "source/ctry/{datetime:yyyy}/{datetime:MM}/{datetime:dd}/{datetime:hh}/event_{systemtime}.json",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting"
    }    
  ]
}
```

***init*.py**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest,outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = 'some_name'
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = 'req_body_test'#req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
        name = 'name'#req_body.get('name')
    
    print(str(req.get_json()))

    outputblob.set(str(req.get_json()))
```

Comment: What is the binding expression {systemtime} suppose to be I have not seen it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic blob name needs you to post a request in json format.

For example, if want to output blob to `test/{testdirectory}/test.txt`, then, you need to post a request like:

```
{
   "testdirectory":"nameofdirectory"
}
```

After that, the binding of azure function will be able to get the directory name.

By the way, I don't recommend binding for complex blob operations. I recommend using SDK more than binding.

Comment: Do you have any example of SDK (Python) to write to azure storage with dynamic path

Comment: @nilesh1212 You can have a look of this offcial doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

Comment: @nilesh1212 Or you can have a look of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953148/saving-file-into-azure-blob/62987514#62987514 Just change the `"MyFirstBlob.txt"` to a dynamic value.

Comment: Hi for connect_str = os.getenv('str') can I set  connect_str = os.getenv('MyStorageConnectionAppSetting') the one I passed in functon.json

Comment: @nilesh1212 Just use `connect_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"`

Comment: ok, I dont want to hardcode the conn string hence wanted to cross check.

Comment: @nilesh1212 If use `connect_str = os.getenv('MyStorageConnectionAppSetting')`, Just put the `MyStorageConnectionAppSetting` to the `values` section of local.settings.json(When you are developing on local). If your app is on azure, put `MyStorageConnectionAppSetting` to the configuration setttings. If you want to secure, use azure key vault to give a reference of the setting.

Comment: @nilesh1212 Binding also reads settings from environment variables. Locally, you need to fill in the values section in local.settings.json, and on azure, you need to fill in the configuration settings. The advantage of using SDK is that you can deal with blob client objects.

Comment: I am able to do it not completly but close to the solution .Thank you so much for the help {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputblob",
      "path": "raw/yotpo/{DateTime:yyyy}/{DateTime:MM}/{DateTime:dd}/event_{DateTime}.json",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting"
    }

Comment: @nilesh1212 What method did you adopt? Do you use binding and then pass in json?

Comment: yes I did the change only in function.json binding section.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to achieve the dynamic path by making below changes to

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputblob",
      "path": "source/ctry/{DateTime:yyyy}/{DateTime:MM}/{DateTime:dd}/event_{DateTime}.json",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting"
    }    
  ]
}
```